# Evaluate $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k+7}}{5^{2^{k}} + 1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Evaluate $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k+7}}{5^{2^{k}} + 1} $

For context, I encountered this question in a recent multiple choice examination.
Here is my solution for this question:-

*Taking $2^{7}$ out of the summation*,
$$
2^7 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k}}{5^{2^{k}} + 1}
$$
*Assuming*,
$$
f(k) =  \frac{2^{k}}{5^{2^{k}} + 1} 
$$
*Multiplying and dividing by $ (5^{2^k} -1)$*,
$$
f(k) =  \frac{2^{k}}{5^{2^{k}} + 1} \cdot \frac{(5^{2^k}-1)}{(5^{2^k}-1)}
$$
*Breaking the denominator using the difference of squares identity,*
$$
f(k) = \frac{2^{k}}{5^{2^{k}} + 1} \cdot \frac{(5^{2^k}-1)}{(5^{2^{k-1}}+1)} \cdot \frac{1}{(5^{2^{k-1}}-1)}
$$
*Using difference of squares identity till the last term,*
$$
f(k) = \frac{2^{k}}{5^{2^{k}} + 1} \cdot \frac{(5^{2^k}-1)}{(5^{2^{k-1}}+1)} ... \frac{1}{(5^{2^{k-k}}+1)} \cdot \frac{1}{(5^{2^{k-k}}-1)}
$$
*Introducing a Product to simplify the term,*
$$
f(k) = \frac{(\prod_{k=0}^{k}(\frac{2}{5^{2^k}+1}))\cdot (5^{2^k} - 1)}{4 \cdot 2}
$$

*Rewriting the previous equation and substituting -1 with (+1-2),*
$$
f(k) = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \left\{\left(\prod_{k=0}^{k}\frac{2}{5^{2^k}+1}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{5^{2^k}+1 -2}{2}\right) \right\}
$$
*Assuming,*
$$
Let\;g(k) = \frac{2}{5^{2^k}+1}
$$

$$
Let\;h(k) = \prod_{k=0}^{k}g(k)
$$
*Substituting,*
$$
f(k) = \frac{1}{4}\cdot \left\{ h(k)\cdot\left( \frac{1}{g(k)}-1 \right) \right\}
$$

$$
f(k)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left\{ \frac{h(k)}{g(k)}-h(k) \right\}
$$

$$
NOTE: \:\frac{h(k)}{g(k)}=h(k-1) \\ \text{For} \:k\ge 1
$$

$$
NOTE: \:\frac{h(0)}{g(0)}=1
$$

*Summing f(k) from 0 to $\infty$*,

$$
\:\: \: f(0)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left\{ \frac{h(0)}{g(0)}-h(0) \right\}
$$
$$
+ \: f(1)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left\{ \frac{h(1)}{g(1)}-h(1) \right\}
$$
$$
+ \: f(2)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left\{ \frac{h(2)}{g(2)}-h(2) \right\}
$$

$$
\vdots
$$
*Simplying,*

$$
f(0)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left\{ 1 -h(0) \right\}
$$
$$
+ \:f(1)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left\{ h(0)-h(1) \right\}
$$
$$
+ \:f(2)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left\{ h(1)-h(2) \right\}
$$
$$
\vdots
$$

*All of the terms except 1 cancel out within the brackets once added.*

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k) = \frac{1}{4}
$$

*Hence, multiplying 128 to this, we get* 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k+7}}{5^{2^{k}} + 1}= 32
$$

Is there any other quick/viable approach to solve this? Especially for a timed examination?

Comment: When asking questions here try to remove trivial details. For example, the term $2^7$ could be completely omitted from this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

See what happens to the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2^k}{a^{2^k}+1}$ when $n=2$: $$\sum_{k=0}^2\frac{2^k}{a^{2^k}+1} = \frac{a^6+2a^5+3a^4+4a^3+5a^2+6a+7}{(a+1)(a^2+1)(a^4+1)} = (a-1)\ a^7\ \frac{\sum_{j=1}^7 j\ a^{-j}}{a^8-1}$$

The last sum is an [Arithmetico-geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence).

Can you generalize for $n$?

Comment: I had not even thought of trying to simply the summation. I am in high school currently so the idea of generalising is a bit new for me. I shall give it a try

Comment: Okay I was able to generalize this for all n. Using the definition that sum till infinity is basically the partial sum if limit is taken to infinity. At infinity, the AGP converges and those terms with infinity in power cancel out to 1 when limits are used. Only 1/4 remains. Limits are not in my course for this year but this is a really elegant approach of solving this. I will try to apply this to some other infinite summation questions that I have. Thanks for this nice idea.

Answer (score 3):

Although it is essentially the same thing, I believe directly establishing a difference relation after the multiplication of the conjugate would significantly reduce the time taken to solve the problem
In general, the expressions of the form
$$ \frac{2^k}{a^{2^k}+1} $$
Can be simplified:
$$ \frac{2^k}{a^{2^k}+1}\cdot\frac{a^{2^k}-1}{a^{2^k}-1}=\frac{2^k(a^{2^k}-1)}{a^{2^{k+1}}-1}$$
Now since we have to make a term such that $t(k) = h(k)-h(k-1)$ or $t(k) = h(k)-h(k+1)$,
$$ \frac{2^k(a^{2^k}-1)}{a^{2^{k+1}}-1} = \frac{2^ka^{2^k}-2^k}{a^{2^{k+1}}-1} = \frac{2^ka^{2^k}-(2^{k+1}-2^k)}{a^{2^{k+1}}-1} $$
$$ = \frac{2^k(a^{2^k}+1)}{a^{2^{k+1}}-1}- \frac{2^{k+1}}{a^{2^{k+1}}-1}   $$
$$ = \frac{2^k}{a^{2^{k}}-1}- \frac{2^{k+1}}{a^{2^{k+1}}-1}$$

Now that we have a function of the type $t(k) = h(k)-h(k+1)$, we can apply the method of difference and hence find the summation.
Sorry for the latex errors, I am not really well versed in the language, hope it helps

Comment: My process also works on this difference relation but I took an unnecessary tangent in the process and made it much longer than required. Nice answer

Comment: I fixed a sign in your answer